# Search for a text in Linux but don't display the complete line in results

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I'm using grep to do this, like:

```
grep someText file.log
```

But this returns the complete line in results. If `someText` is found in the middle of a line I don't want to ouput the whole line, just the part after and including the `someText`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append a `.*` to your search and use the `-o` (`--only-matching`) option:

```
grep 'someText.*' -o file.log
```